# Node.js setTimeout() works with wrapped function but not with the same function unwrapped

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, sails.js

I'm having a hard time understanding how Node.js `setTimeout()` works - or rather, why a specific example doesn't.

A Node.js MVC framework, Sails.js, has an `update(criteria, values)` function that updates the attributes of models with `criteria` to `values`, for example `User.update({name: 'Frank'}, {age: 20})` would update the age of all Frank-named users. I'm trying to execute an update query after a timeout, using the syntax described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html):

```
setTimeout(User.update, 2000, {name: 'Frank'}, {age: 20})
```

This doesn't actually seem to update anything. However, when I wrap the function in a simple wrapper:

```
function testTimeout(criteria, values) {
    return User.update(criteria, values)
    .then(function(tasks) {
        return;
    });
}
```

and then call the timeout with the wrapper as first argument:

```
setTimeout(testTimeout, 2000, {name: 'Frank'}, {age: 20})
```

the user is correctly updated. I'd like to understand why this happens, and how I could execute the timeout with as little extra code as possible.

Comment: In first case your callback isn't bound to `User` object. Correct code: `setTimeout(User.update.bind(User), 2000, {name: 'Frank'}, {age: 20})`

Comment: in the first example, the query is executed straight away, and setTimeout is receiving, probably, null (depends what returns User.update method)

Comment: I think that calling User.update doesn't do anything  it doesn't connect to db at all until it's executed using `then(...);`  which means the second example is only way to do it.

Comment: That must be it. Looking at sails docs for `.exec()`, it says `If you don't run .exec() or use promises, your query will not execute.` Thanks for clearing this up for me!